# Kubuntu hangs in the splash screen after login

Tags: kubuntu

I  switched my wife's notebook from Ubuntu 10.10 to Kubuntu 10.10 (by installing kubuntu-desktop), but sometimes (not always) after filling in username and password, Kububtu hangs in the post-login splash screen (as if it would take forever to bring up the desktop).

CPU usage is not high. I have no idea why it happens.

I saw reports of some problems with login, but not specifically like this (hanging on that splash screen after loggin in). Did this happen to anyone else? Is there any fix or workaround that I could try?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem always happened due to bad drivers for me.I fixed it by disabling Compositing.

Comment: Thanks! How do I disable compositing? (I would know how to do that if there was an xorg.conf file, but there isn't one and I don't know how X configuration is handled these days).

Comment: Found out how to do it; will see if it stops freezing!

Comment: Could you share your knowledge? How did you disable?